# Le dije a mi maestra de lengua que esta oración es incorrecta por el uso de la coma

Tags: ortografía

"Juan Pablo segundo nació en Polonia, en cambio Benedicto XVI es alemán.".
Le comenté que debería ir una coma después de "en cambio", o bien, un punto y coma antes de la conjunción. Lo último lo he investigado y, según yo, sí es incorrecto, pero lo primero que dijo no lo es. ¿Estoy bien o ella lo está?
Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Es correcto que la oración:

1. Juan Pablo II nació en Polonia, en cambio Benedicto XVI es alemán.

está mal puntuada.

Para que la coma funcione, debería haber más de dos proposiciones coordinadas, y no debería haber un conector del tipo "en cambio":

2. Juan Pablo II nació en Polonia, Benedicto XVI es alemán y Francisco es oriundo de Argentina.

Para que la oración (1) sea correcta, efectivamente se debe colocar punto y coma antes de "en cambio" y una coma después:

1'. Juan Pablo II nació en Polonia; en cambio, Benedicto XVI es alemán.

Nota: "Según yo" me suena horrible. [Según Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/se-puede-decir-segun-yo/), hay mejores formas de expresar la opinión de uno.